# Table thead :display on tr:hover

Tags: html-table, hover, highlight

I want to reproduce the effect on this website http://sires.crv4all.us/shop/us/catalog/Holstein

When you hover a `<tr>` it displays the thead information above the `<tr>` line your cursor is.

I tried using a jQuery tooltip but it displays the thead on top. I want to find out how to make it display for the tr line you are hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVDm7/6/) I made producing this effect (I'm kinda new to JS/jquery so please feel free to critique my code, i know its pretty inefficient).

On the page itself it looks like this JS is driving it:

```
  var $div = $('<div class="floating-header" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none"><table><thead></thead></table></div>');
    $(document.body).prepend($div);

    var $source = $('#animals thead');

    // Lock widths
    $source.find('th').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css({width: + $this.width() + 'px'});
    })

    // Position floater
    $div.find('thead').append($source.html());
    var offset = $source.offset();
    $div.css({
      left: offset.left,                                                       
      top: offset.top
    })

    // Strip off junk
    $th = $div.find('th');
    var thIdx = 0;
    var thLength = $th.length;
            var cartEnabled = false;

    $th.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.html($this.find('a').text());
      if (thIdx<=2 || (cartEnabled && thIdx==(thLength-1))) $this.css({opacity:0});
      thIdx++;
    });

    // Exclude first row (initial state on page load; updated by facets.js)
    $('#animals tbody tr:visible').first().addClass('no-header');

    var HEADER_HEIGHT = $div.height();

    // Set-up events
    $('#animals tbody tr').mouseover(function(){
      var $row = $(this);

      setMyTimeout(function(){
        if ($row.hasClass('no-header')) return;
        $div.stop().css({
          top: ($row.offset().top - HEADER_HEIGHT) + 'px',
          left: $row.offset().left, 
        opacity: 0.5}).fadeIn(200);
      },100);
    });

    $('#animals tbody tr').mouseout(function(){
      setMyTimeout(function(){
        $div.fadeOut(200);
      },50);
    });
  });
```